# Programming manually a userForm - First step : Sub or Function not defined in simple userForm VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos

My goal is to code manually a userForm with Excel VBA (2018 MacOS version).

Being a beginner and confirming the unavailability of inserting userform in Excel 2018 MacOS, I have started by a simple VBA script example from : https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/#A_Modal_Example

```
' PROCEDURE CODE
Sub UseModal()

    ' Create and show form
    Dim frm As New UserFormFruit

    ' Display Userform - The code in this procedure
    ' will wait here until the form is closed
    frm.Show
    
    ' Display the returned value
    MsgBox "The user has selected " & frm.Fruit
        
    ' Close the form
    Unload frm
    Set frm = Nothing

End Sub

' USERFORM CODE
' Returns the textbox value to the calling procedure
Public Property Get Fruit() As Variant
    Fruit = textboxFruit.Value
End Property
```

But I get "**type used not defined**".

Here a screenshot of my project interface :

[image: Screenshot of interface]

I would like to know where is my error: how to define the type used?

(I am using Excel 2018 for MacOS).

Comment: You need to create a user form called “UserFormFruit.” Right click in the project browser and add new user form. Then name it “UserFormFruit”

Comment: @Philip556677 thanks for your answer. On Excell 2018 for MacOS version, adding userForm functionality is not available, I can only code directly the userForm, there is not UI designer, this comes from the following post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399661/userform-with-excel-2018-for-macos . Adding user form functionality is available on Windows Excel 2018 version or Excel 2011 for MacOS version. Have I got other alternatives for the code of my question above ?

Comment: Other than coding the class manually. You may be able to use a designer tool and import the form to vba.

Comment: Does a such designer tool exist in Pack Office ?

Comment: Coding the class manually : have you got a link or tutorial to acheive it ?

Comment: I have found maybe a begin of solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956591/excel-vba-add-code-userform-programmatically/27459772#27459772 but I don't know how to use this Public Function inside Visual Basic editor and execute it or include it into module ? any suggestion is welcome